# how to use PHP session variable in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know how to use PHP session variable in zend framework

here is my code so far :-

```
 public function loginAction()
    {
        $this->view->title = 'Login';
        if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
            $this->_redirect('index/index');
        }

            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $form = new Default_Form_LoginForm();
            if($request->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())){
                $authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();

                $username = $form->getValue('username');
                $password = $form->getValue('password');

                $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                            ->setCredential($password);

                $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
                $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

                if($result->isValid()){
                    $identity = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();

        print_r($authAdapter->getResultRowObject());

                    $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
                    $authStorage->write($identity);

        echo $authAdapter->getIdentity() . "\n\n";

           //         $this->_redirect('index/index');
                } else {
                    $this->view->errorMessage = "User name or password is wrong.";
                }
            }
        }


        $this->view->form = $form;

     }
```

now i want to store username in session and i want to use in some other page like

`echo "welcome," .$this->username;`  what i can do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of writing `$identity` to `$authStorage`, you can store a custom object or a model.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

class      Application_Model_UserSession
implements Zend_Acl_Role_Interface
{
    public $userId;
    public $username;

    /** @var array */
    protected $_data;

    public function __construct($userId, $username)
    {
        $this->userId   = $userId;
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) {
            return $this->_data[$name];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function updateStorage()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $auth->getStorage()->write($this);
    }

    public function getRoleId()
    {
        // TODO: implement
        $role = 'guest';
        return $role;
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->_data[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($this->_data[$name]);
    }
}
```

Now in your login controller you can do:

```
if($result->isValid()){
    $identity = new Application_Model_UserSession(0, $username); // 0 for userid

    // You can also store other data in the session, e.g.:
    $identity->account = new Account_Model($authAdapter->getResultRowObject());

    $identity->updateStorage(); // update Zend_Auth identity with the UserSession object
```

Typically, I have an account object that I also store in the UserSession object, and make easy access to the username and userId via public properties.

Now at any time you can get the object:

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity(); // Application_Model_UserSession
```

Just don't forget to make sure it is a Application_Model_UserSession.

Comment: I love your answer, but it might be a little overkill for this question. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Although you can create Zend_Session class object, however I would recommend Zend_Session_Namespace object instead. You can instantiate session as:

```
$sess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('MyNamespace');
```

If don’t pass, Zend Session Namespace will assign its name a string “default”.
To store values, you will need to do the following:

```
$sess->username = 'you_name';
```

Later in your code, you will need to do the following to retrieve value from the session:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('MyNamespace');
$userName = $sess->username;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

In this case it should be as simple as continuing to add the data to your $authStorage:

```
$authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
$authStorage->write($identity);
$authStorage->write($username);
```

later in another action or controller you can either use Zend_Auth::getStorage to recall your data or use Zend_Session_Namespace.

```
    $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
    $authStorage->read($identity);
    $authStorage->read($username);
```

or

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth'); //Zend_Auth uses Zend_Session_Namespace for storage
$username = $session->username;
```

Comment: Just a note, if you `write` to the storage more than once, it will overwrite the previous value, so storing an object or stdClass would be the way to go so you can change the object's properties.

Comment: @drew010 I remember that. Seems like the correct way would be to store everything in storage using one write statement. I think I'll have to experiment with this some more. Thanks for the tip.